# What's an efficient way to render child items of one of many list items in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that renders a few list items, and some of those may contain another set of child items inside of a `<ul>` tag when the parent list item is clicked.

This is a rather large dataset so what would be an efficient way to render (and destroy on second click) the child items when the parent list item is clicked?

Example code below:

```
const Timeline = ({ edges }) => {

    const getChildren = async id => {
        
    }

    return (
        <ul className={styles.timeline}>
            {edges.sort((a, b) => formatDate(a.node.date) - formatDate(b.node.date)).map(({ node }, index) => (
                <li key={node.id} className="timeline-item">
                    {!node.children.edges.length > 0 ? (
                        <a className="timeline-item-link" onClick={() => getChildren(node.id)}>
                            <h2 className="timeline-item-title">{node.title}</h2>
                        </a>
                        <ul className="timeline-children"></ul>
                    ) : null}
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    )

}
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The big thing is you're going to want to make each of the parent elements their own component. Otherwise react needs to rerender the whole list anytime anything changes. Something like:

```
const Timeline = ({ edges }) => {
    return (
        <ul className={styles.timeline}>
            {edges.sort((a, b) => formatDate(a.node.date) - formatDate(b.node.date)).map(({ node }, index) => (
                <TimelineChild node={node} key={index} />
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}


const TimelineChild = ({ node }) => {
    const getChildren = async id => {
        
    }
    
    return (<li key={node.id} className="timeline-item">
                    {!node.children.edges.length > 0 ? (
                        <a className="timeline-item-link" onClick={() => getChildren(node.id)}>
                            <h2 className="timeline-item-title">{node.title}</h2>
                        </a>
                        <ul className="timeline-children"></ul>
                    ) : null}
                </li>);
}
```

You may also want to give all the `node.children` their own component, too.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to render the child list items when the parent is clicked?

Comment: If you already have the children loaded (as is suggested by `node.children.edges`) you can simply toggle a `useState` boolean. If you need to load them dynamically (as suggested by `getChildren`) then you should `useState` an array.